# Do math in MySQL Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with the following columns:

```
id
user_id
price
```

One example row:

```
1
1
{price}+27
```

Now I want to pass the variable price in the query (e.g. price=10) and to get the calculated column; in this case I want to get:

```
1
1
37
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you use any scripting language like PHP in your frontend or you would like to do this from the backend?

Comment: I use PHP in Frontend

Comment: You can easily replace the variable {price} using PHP:
$col_data = str_replace('{price}', 10, $row['price']);  print eval("return ($col_data);");

Comment: I know, but in my production environment there are a lot of rows and the mysql server is quicker than a PHP script that has to loop through all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

can't you just do

```
UPDATE exampleTable
    SET price = price + 27;
```

Comment: No, I need to select a huge table with prices for each user. Each user has a individual price formula, for example user 1 has price 7+ **3** and user 2 has price 7+ **8**

Comment: so you have user to base price relationship in a table somewhere, do you have a separate table with a user to variable price mapping as well? I'm a little confused now.

Comment: Yes, I have a user-table and a relation-table from the user to the price mapping. In the price mapping table the price formula for each user is stored.

Comment: What would be an example value from the price formula field?

Comment: Agreed but if we figure out what OP meant by "formula" maybe we could help him out..

Comment: You could add two fields together easily assuming there is tables for userid-baseprice & userid-varprice mapping by doing : update tableA set a.basePrice = b.varPrice + a.basePrice from tableA a, tableB b where a.userId = b.userId;  but i still dont understand what op means by formula, is it a string with variable names and operators?